# Using FileHelperAsyncEngine in F#

Tags: csv, asynchronous, f#, filehelpers

I am trying to load rows from a csv files to an Elasticsearch database in f# using FileHelpers to read the csv. Everything is working for small test files with the code snippet below reading all records at once

```
let readRows<'T>(filePath:string) =
    let engine = FileHelperEngine(typeof<'T>)

    engine.ReadFile(filePath)
    |> Array.map (fun row -> row :?> 'T)
```

Unfortunately it needs to be able read larger files, of which many columns are discarded later, line by line. The function FileHelperAsyncEngine.BeginReadFile returns an IDisposable.

```
let readRowsAsync<'T>(filePath:string) =
    let engine = new FileHelperAsyncEngine(typeof<'T>)

    engine.BeginReadFile(filePath:string)
    |> ...
```

**How can I further process this object to an Array of <'T>s?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://www.filehelpers.net/docs/html/M_FileHelpers_FileHelperAsyncEngine_1_BeginReadFile.htm), after you call `BeginReadFile`, the `engine` itself becomes an enumerable sequence over which you can iterate (which is a very strange design decision). So you can just build your own sequence on top of it:

```
let readRowsAsync<'T>(filePath:string) = 
  seq {
    let engine = new FileHelperAsyncEngine(typeof<'T>)
    use disposable = engine.BeginReadFile(filePath)

    for r in engine do
      if not (shouldDiscard r) then yield (map r)
  }
```

Note that I'm using the `use` binding, rather than `let`. This will ensure that the disposable is disposed after the sequence ends or the consumer stops iterating over it.

Note that the following will **not** work, even though it will compile:

```
let readRowsAsync<'T>(filePath:string) = 
  let engine = new FileHelperAsyncEngine(typeof<'T>)
  use disposable = engine.BeginReadFile(filePath)

  engine |> Seq.filter (not << shouldDiscard) |> Seq.map map
```

If you do it this way, the disposable will be disposed after the function returns, but before the resulting enumeration is iterated over, thus closing the file before its time. To ensure that the disposable is correctly disposed, you must enclose the whole thing in a `seq` expression.

If you really want to use `Seq.filter`/`Seq.map` instead of `for`/`yield`, you can still do this, but inside the `seq` expression, like this:

```
let readRowsAsync<'T>(filePath:string) = 
  seq {
    let engine = new FileHelperAsyncEngine(typeof<'T>)
    use disposable = engine.BeginReadFile(filePath)

    yield! engine |> Seq.filter (not << shouldDiscard) |> Seq.map map
  }
```

You can also bring the filtering and mapping out of the `seq` expression (which would make your function more reusable), but the `seq` expression itself must remain in place, because it controls the disposing part:

```
let readRowsAsync<'T>(filePath:string) = 
  seq {
    let engine = new FileHelperAsyncEngine(typeof<'T>)
    use disposable = engine.BeginReadFile(filePath)

    yield! engine
  }

let results = 
  readRowsAsync<SomeType>( "someFile.txt" )
  |> Seq.filter (not << shouldDiscard) 
  |> Seq.map map
```

Finally, it must be noted that you should be careful handling this sequence, because it's holding on to an unmanaged resource (i.e. open file): don't hold it open for a long time, don't employ blocking operations while processing it, etc.

Comment: Nice answer. Alternatively, since `engine` is an `IEnumerable<'T>`, you can use `Seq.filter` to do the discard test. This allows you to replace the for loop with `yield! Seq.filter shouldKeep engine`. If you also need the mapping part, then it'd be `yield! engine |> Seq.filter shouldKeep |> Seq.map mappingFn`. =)

Comment: Thanks Fyodor and Roujo! Help me very much :)

Comment: If you use `Seq.filter`, you don't have control over when to dispose the disposable. So don't do this!

Comment: I modified the answer, clarifying the different ways to do filtering and mapping, and why some of them are less preferable than others,

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Good point, didn't think of that. Thank you! =)